# How to create a Container Instance of an external image with Pulumi?

Tags: azure, docker, continuous-integration, github-actions, pulumi

I am using Pulumi to provision Azure infrastructure and would like to create a Container Instance that uses the neo4j image from Docker Hub. To achieve this, I need an Azure Container Registry (ACR) containing the neo4j image.

I have tried the following approaches:

1. Using a [pulumi docker image](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/docker/api-docs/image/). This has proven to be unsuccessful, as it can only add to the ACR images which are built from a Dockerfile I have locally.
2. I read the documentation of [RegistryImage](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/docker/api-docs/registryimage/) and [RemoteImage](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/docker/api-docs/remoteimage/). At first glance it looks like these could be fixes for my problem, but I couldn't figure out how to add the RemoteImage to my ACR or to use the RegistryImage, as it looks like it still needs a Dockerfile.
3. Considering an alternative approach where I am creating the ACR and a Service Principal which has permission to import the image in my ACR. Afterwards, I would create a pipeline in which I would import the image with `az import`. Lastly, I would have to come back at Pulumi and create the Container Instance.

Here's part of my code for achieving that:

```js
const Cr = new Registry(...)
const App = new Application(...)
const Sp = new ServicePrincipal(...)
const ImportRole = new RoleDefinition(...)
const SpRole = new RoleAssignment(...)
```

Having these, I continue as a next step in my pipeline with:

```yaml
...
jobs:
  publish-image:
    ...
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      ...
      - name: AZ Login
        uses: Azure/login@v1.1
        with: <Service Principal Credentials here>
      - name: Import to ACR
        runs: az acr import ...
```

Finally, I try running Pulumi again, just with the remaining Container Instance component to be generated.

I tried all these things and I don't seem to be reaching any solution. Is there any way to directly create a Container Instance simultaneously with an ACR while also using an external Image?